# Too many redirects PHP contact form

Tags: php, html, forms, email, redirect

My website say there are too many redirects, it happens when you try to submit a form which is to be mailed to a email. The link between the two is correct.

form code:

```
<section class="linksMain">
      <div class="form-style-5">
        <form action="../php/main/contact1.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Personelijke informatie</legend>
          <input class="form" type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Je naam *">
          <input class="form" type="email" name="field2" placeholder="Je email *">
          <input class="form" type="text" name="field3" placeholder="Onderwerp">
          <label for="job">Categorie</label>
          <select id="job" name="field4">
              <option value="School">School</option>
              <option value="Stage">Stage</option>
              <option value="Media">Media INN</option>
              <option value="Copt">Copyright</option>
              <option value="Opdracht">Opdracht</option>
              <option value="Opdracht">VKG</option>
              <option value="Opdracht">Privé</option>
              <option value="other_indoor">Anders</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>      
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Bericht</legend>
          <textarea class="form" name="field5" placeholder="Over jezelf"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Verstuur" />
        </form>
      </div>    
    </section>
```

PHP code:

```
#This sends emails to inbox@driekvandermeulen.nl, the filler of the email comes from a form in main/contact.php

$name = $POST['field1'];
$email = $POST['field2'];
$subject = $POST['field3'];
$category = $POST['field4'];
$message = $POST['field5'];

$mailTo = "inbox@driekvandermeulen.nl";
$headers = "From:".$mailFrom;
$txt = "Je hebt een email gekregen van".$name.".\n\n".$message;

mail($mailTo, $subject, $category, $headers);
header("Location: contact1.php?mailsend");
```

Answer (score 0):

The header location you are changing to `header("Location: contact1.php?mailsend");` will trigger a redirect. And so on. You have to catch the `?mailsend` query and check if passed to stop the code.

```
if ($_GET['mailsend'] == false) {
  mail($mailTo, $subject, $category, $headers);
  header("Location: contact1.php?mailsend");
}
```